# Filtrado API Rest Framework Django (Campo extra FK)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, djangorestframework

Quisiera poder filtrar por el valor de otro campo de la tabla (FK) no solo por `id`.

Ahora mismo si escribo `http://www.domain.com/api/preguntas/?language=1` me devuelve los resultados que quiero, pero yo quisiera poder filtrar de la siguiente manera (por otro campo de la FK (tabla Lenguajes campo shortname) `http://www.domain.com/api/preguntas/?language=ES`.

Por otro lado he logrado filtrar una tabla normal por otro campo sin muchos problemas, incluso varios parámetros. Pero en una tabla relacionada.. no sé como hacerlo.

```
http://www.domain.com/api/respuestas/?pregunta=1&contenido=PHP
```

En este caso me filtra de la tabla respuestas las que sean de la pregunta 1 y tengan de contenido PHP. Quisiera hacer exactamente lo mismo pero filtrando por campos de la tabla relacionada.

La cosa es que tengo que devolver todas las preguntas con sus respectivas respuestas filtradas por idioma o por categoría.

Tendré que usar el *Django Rest Framework Multiple Models*??? Para poder cruzar las tablas?

Comment: Interesante, tenía que hacer múltiples idiomas en mi blog y esto me va ayudar muchísimo, pienso que haces una view en función agregas @api_view(['GET']), traes el queryset con los parámetros nada más

Answer (score 1):

Despues que tengas configurado tu [filtro](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends) puedes hacer los filtros como si se tratase de un queryset usando la notacion de doble guión bajo (__). Ejemplos:

```
http://www.domain.com/api/preguntas/?language__slug=ES

http://www.domain.com/api/respuestas/?pregunta__user_id=200&contenido=Python
```